# Estimate the error if $P_2 = 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$ is used to to estimate the value of $\cos(x)$ with $x<0.1$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

The answer is error lower than $5\cdot10^{-6}$.

\begin{align}
f(0)& = \cos(x)\\
f'(0)& = -\sin(x)\\
f''(0)& = -\cos(x)\\
f'''(0)& = \sin(x)\\
f^4(0)& = \cos(x)
\end{align}

We also have that
$$P_2(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)x^2}{2}$$
and
$$P_3(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)x^2}{2} + \frac{f'''(0)x^3}{6}$$

Using the Lagrange Remainder: for $n=3$,

$$| R_3(x)| \leq  \frac{\cos^4(c)}{4!}x^4 \leq \frac{(0.1)^4}{24} = 0.00000041 < 0.000005$$

I'm not understanding why the value of $n$ is equal to 3.

If the result is equal to $1-x^2/2$ in both $P_2(x)$ and $P_3(x)$, why do I have to take $n$ as 3? Why don't use it as 2?

Comment: Because $\frac{0.1^3}{3!}$ is not smaller than $0.000005$.

Comment: $n$ is just the number of terms you have. $R_n$ is the error after $n$ terms.